# sikuli with Hudson possible?

Tags: hudson, ui-automation, sikuli

We have a windows-based app to install our app using the InstallAnywhere wizard.
We also have a linux-based app to install our app using InstallAnywhere wizard.
Can sikuli be used with Hudson, a continuous integration tool, to automate this installation process ?

If not, do you have other suggestions on how we can accomplish our goal of GUI installation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to accomplish your goal using Sikuli. Good place to start is the [How to run Sikuli from Command Line](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html) documentation section. Personally I managed to automate my iOS integration testing with Sikuli and Jenkins, so I guess you should be able to do what you want as long as you can run your Sikuli scripts from the command line through Hudson. I'm happy to help if you have any more specific questions.

Edit:
As you requested, here is what I call:

```
/Applications/Sikuli-IDE.app/sikuli-ide.sh -t test.sikuli
```

But I don't think it will help you much. I think it's actually you who should show some command line calls and output. And some more details about your install wizard, so we could identify the cause of the leaked process. Also, first thing I did when developing my solution was to actually launch it on my local machine, see if it works, and only after I'm sure it behaves as expected deploy it on the CI.

Comment: hi lawicko thanks for the response. but we still cant get it to work

Comment: hi lawicko could you provide your command line example to share. We're on windows here; we keep getting Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information